# Hadoop: how to correctly decommission nodes on cluster?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, openstack

I've been trying to change number of nodes in my Hadoop cluster (in total 5 nodes including 1 master and 4 workers) by following this solution [change number of data nodes in Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508169/change-number-of-data-nodes-in-hadoop) and this useful post [Commissioning and Decommissioning of Datanode in Hadoop Cluster](https://acadgild.com/blog/commissioning-and-decommissioning-of-datanode-in-hadoop)

Now I can see that on HDFS I have successfully decommissioned one node:
[HDFS screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeyHa.png)

I have set up a exclude file property in my hdfs-site.xml [hdfs.xml screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzZ4P.png) as well as yarn-site.xml [yarn-site.xml screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8pFg.png) which includes the ip address of the node that I want to decommission. Like follow: [excludes file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ7Lo.png)

Also I have done refreshing the nodes commands.

Finally I run `hadoop dfsadmin –report` and I can see the node is actually decommissioned : [nodes report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YnlU.png)

However, on MapReduce cluster metrics I found that there are 5 active nodes and **the node that has been decommissioned on HDFS is not indentified in decommissioned nodes here**.

see: [hadoop cluster metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHwVC.png)

Why is that?

Comment: HDFS uses DataNodes, YARN uses NodeManagers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue solves when I changed name of the host on exclude file. The node name should not contain any port number